# Pagination MVC - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hi all i wonder if someone can give me some help. I've written some sql that will perform some server side pagination, this is working fine when i'm executing it manually. However i want to build a user interface and obviously allow the user to page through each page of data. I'm quite new to mvc and i'm struggling on how to come up with a solution to execute a stored procedure passing in the pageSize and pageNumber. I've worked out how to execute the stored procedure, but struggling on how to do the pagination part. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you be clearer on what part of the paging you are struggling with?  If the SP works OK isn't it just a case of keeping track of what 'page' you are on and passing it in to the SP?

Comment: Yes the sp is working fine, i'm just struggling with the actual paging mechanism in mvc

Comment: It's a mental block - there is no real paging doing it the way you are doing it - all you need to remember between MVC controller actions (like Next or Previous) is what set of data you are on (i.e. the last parameter you passed to the SP, and then increment/decrement it). Either keep the 'page' number in your model/viewmodel or use ViewData or ..... hidden fields. Hopefully the answer from JOBG will get you there but half the battle is to forget that you are trying to 'page'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this implementation of paging in MVC
http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/
It comes with a demo project

With this you just use this helper in the View and it takes care of all the dirty work:

```
<%= Html.Pager(ViewData.Model.PageSize, ViewData.Model.PageNumber, ViewData.Model.TotalItemCount, new { categoryname = ViewData["CategoryDisplayName"] } )%>
```